# Argument of HTMLElement type expected by console.select()

Tags: html, asp.net

when i am trying to browse my application i am getting following error,

> "Argument of HTMLElement type expected by console.select()."

can anyone suggest me the solution to fix this?

please find screen shot of error.

[image]

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDR6g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once.

Just try cleaning (right click on solution > clean) your solution and deploying it again.